# separate string if they had extensions vb net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm working in a program to download all the attachments linked to one record on database, the record on database is stored like "attach1.pdf attach2.docx".

How could i separate in two differents strings?

Something like this:
string1=Attach1.pdf
string2=attach2.docx

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim fileNames As String() = String.Split({" "c})
```

Space delimiting file names is incredibly dumb since most filesystems consider the space character to be a valid path character.

Comment: How about using Regex to separate them? Check the space after dot with N character

Comment: @Alex:  the "dot" typically refers to the file extension, however extensions are not a requirement (`This is a file` is a perfectly valid file name on windows and *nix systems).  Additionally many filesystems, including NTFS and those common to *nix, allow for multiple dots in a file name.  So I'm not sure how regex is going to help parse "`This. Is. A. Perfectly. Valid File.Name`" when the delimiter is a space.  The OP should really choose an invalid path character, such as `|` or `NUL`, for their list delimiter.